# can't be able to reload the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function setAction(){ 
  var value; 
  var id = document.getElementById('id').value;
  if(document.getElementById('action1').checked==true){ 
    value = "Active" 
  }
  else if(document.getElementById('action2').checked==true){ 
    value = "Inactive"; 
  }
  else{ 
    value = "other"; 
  } 
  jConfirm('Are you continue?', 'Confirmation Dialog', function(r) {
  if(r==true){ 
    var strURL="process.php?task=setActionProposal&id="+id+"&status="+value+"&value="+document.getElementById('other').value; 
    var req = getXMLHTTP(); 
    if (req) { 
      document.getElementById('loader').style.display='block'
      req.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (req.readyState == 4) { 
          // only if "OK" 
          if (req.status == 200) { 
            //alert(req.responseText); 
            obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText); 
            if(obj.valid==true){ 
              document.getElementById('loader').style.display='none';
              window.location.href='user.php'; 
            } 
          } 
          else { 
            // alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText); 
          } 
        } 
      } 
      req.open("GET", strURL, true); 
      req.send(null); 
    } 
  }
  else{ } 
  //jAlert('Confirmed: ' + r, 'Confirmation Results'); }); 
}
```

---

My page is not redirecting what's wrong with this can any one solved out                                               I need to redirect with `window.location.href='user.php';`

Comment: try `location.replace("user.php");`

Comment: I did but its not working I just console and found Object {posts: Array[0], success: false, msg: "No record found"}msg: "No record found"posts: Array[0]success: false__proto__: Object

Comment: The object you just posted does not contain a variable "valid" so the code will not go into the if statement: `if(obj.valid==true){ ` may be you ment to check for the `obj.success`?

Comment: obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

so is there any error with JSON.parse
also let me for debug the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try with your full project path
ie,

**window.location = 'your project path/user.php';**

Comment: that good but obj = JSON.parse(req.responseText); has success fail

Answer (score 0):

At first,
You check that,

```
 window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

this will work correctly.
Then the issue is your project path.